# OneNote: Creating new notebook via VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, onenote

I'm trying to create a new notebook in OneNote from VBA. Ultimately, records in excel will automatically pull to new notes inside of a predefined section within a predefined notebook. IF the notebook and/or the section doesn't exist, it is created.

I'm trying to use the UpdateHierarchy method to upload a new XML schema with the new notebook. I can't quite put a PATH down, since I want this script to be able to adapt to whatever user is using it (unless maybe I can grab the path from the context?).

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853(v=office.14).aspx),

> If you pass only a partial OneNote XML string...OneNote attempts to
>   infer the changes you want. For example, if you include a NOTEBOOK
>   element that contains only one section, OneNote adds the section after
>   any existing sections.

I took this to mean that I can supply partial XML and OneNote will autofill the rest. I can't find anywhere showing the minimum for adding a new notebook, and the following code produces:

> hrNotebookDoesNotExist 0x80042015 The notebook does not exist.

Here is the code:

```
Dim oneNote As OneNote14.Application
Set oneNote = New OneNote14.Application

Dim targetNotebook As String, targetSection As String, targetPage As String
targetNotebook = "The Notes"
targetSection = "Notes"

Dim notebookXml As String

oneNote.GetHierarchy "", hsNotebooks, notebookXml, xs2010

Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

If doc.LoadXML(notebookXml) Then
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim notebookName As String, notebookPath As String, notebookId As String

    Set nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("one:Notebook")

    For Each node In nodes
        notebookName = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text

        If notebookName = targetNotebook Then
            notebookPath = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("path").Text
            notebookId = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
        End If

    Next

If notebookId = vbNullString Then

            'create new notebook
            Dim newNotebookXml As String
            newNotebookXml = "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
                            & "<one:Notebooks xmlns:one=" & Chr(34) & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote" & Chr(34) & ">" _
                                & "<one:Notebook name=" & Chr(34) & "HUD Notes" & Chr(34) & ">" _
                                & "</one:Notebook>" _
                            & "</one:Notebooks>"
            Debug.Print (newNotebookXml)
            oneNote.UpdateHierarchy newNotebookXml  'This is where the error hits
End If

...
```

the code continues, but is irrelevant for this question.

How can I change the code around to create a notebook named targetNotebook if it is not found and notebookId is null?

Thank you!